# How to center align a Div correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble correctly centering [my website](http://www.voltageguitar.com)

It seems to be centered when I zoom out. but to a user that doesn't zoom out it looks out of place. any suggestions? the site was created with all AP divs it doesn't center correctly even when trying to use the following:

```
<div align="center">
```

Comment: There is nothing salvageable from this code.  You need a lot more information than a single SO thread will provide.  Try irc://irc.freenode.net/css

Comment: put everything inside a common div and set its position to be relative and float and margin it accordingly , rest will be fine

Answer (score 5):

Try **`margin:0 auto;`** for the container div it will center align your div :)

**[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/PeRSs/2/)**

**[See the fullscreen view of the result](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/hhmUD/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Nope, because as he said, he's absolutely positioned ("AP") everything.

Comment: You can still use this with absolute positioning, as long as you wrap the absolutely positioned content in a containing block-style element with `position: relative`.  Then the container should be the element on which you set `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: You can, if you don't care that it won't make any difference.

Answer (score -1):

your design is not correct in my opinion. you must:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
from apdiv1 to 31
</div>
<div id="content">*/instead of blockquote*/
put content
</div>
<div id="footer">
put content</div>
</div>
</body>
```

with css
body{background-image:concrete bkg.jpg}

```
#wrapper{margin:0 auto}
```

more more more...
brgds

Comment: Needs a doctype declaration and a few other things.

Answer (score -1):

In css

add property

```
body
{
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```